# Does this EXPTIME-complete construction work for every DTIME?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I came up with the following after reading the Wikipedia page about EXPTIME, and I am wondering if I am right. I don't think I invented it, I just don't have any textbooks about this subject to find the answer in.

**Background**

The question of what state a Turing machine will be in after *k* steps is a simple example of a problem that is $\mathrm{EXPTIME}$-complete. The problem is in $\mathrm{EXPTIME}$ because it can be solved by simulating the machine for $2^{length(k)}$ steps, and since the turing machine specification can only lengthen the input, that's enough time. The problem is $\mathrm{EXPTIME}$-complete because the given Turing machine can be one that takes less than $k$ steps to solve any other problem. Moreover, since there's no way to simulate a Turing machine for $k$ steps in fewer than $k$ steps, this proves that there is a problem in $\mathrm{EXPTIME}$ that is not in any lower time class (preventing hierarchy collapse).

**The part I thought up**

Bearing in mind that simulating a Turing machine has a constant-factor overhead, I believe that this technique can be used to create problems that are $\mathrm{DTIME(t(n))}$-complete for any well-behaved $t(n)$. Given an $t(n)$, here is a program that should be $\mathrm{DTIME(t(n))}$-complete:

1. Read $n$ in unary (e.g. $n=5$ would be represented by a symbol repeated five times).
2. Read a Turing machine specification followed by its input, which will be comparable to $n$ in length on the tape.
3. Compute $t(n)$ and simulate the Turing machine for that many steps.

This should rule out hierarchy collapse because there is no faster algorithm for solving the problem.

A couple stipulations on $t(n)$ must be applied: it must be computable in a time bounded by itself (it must grow as fast or faster than the number of steps needed to compute it, or else the above program wouldn't be in $\mathrm{DTIME(t(n))}$), and it also should at least be linear. (Turing machines aren't appropriate for studying sublinear-time algorithms.)

The reduction that proves completeness would simply be setting up the above, writing $n$ many symbols to the tape in a run about as long as the input to the simulated machine, and then writing the simulated machine and its input. That can happen in linear time.

If the above is correct, not only is there at least one problem in every $\mathrm{DTIME}$, at least one problem in every $\mathrm{DTIME}$ is $\mathrm{DTIME}$-complete for that $\mathrm{DTIME}$, and furthermore, that problem is not in any lower $\mathrm{DTIME}$. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: I'm not convinced by your EXPTIME-hardness proof. You're not using the definition of EXPTIME-hard.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The definition of EXPTIME-hard is that a polynomial-time reduction exists from any problem in EXPTIME to the given problem. The reduction is providing (k, a Turing machine that solves the other problem, the instance of the other problem) to the algorithm I described. That's a linear-time reduction and therefore a polynomial-time reduction. The other implicit step I elided was combining being in the class with being hard to prove completeness.